Why is VS Code is missing value suggestions for the CSS white-space property?
when I use the value of white-space in my CSS document, its values ​​are not suggested to me, and I must use the ctrl+space keys.
But the second problem is that when these suggestions are displayed with the help of the keys, it does not show me all the features of white-space and only shows 3 items.
I have uploaded screenshots for you to understand better
(https://i.sstatic.net/26Pkh4WM.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/3KmqrAtl.png)

The way VS Code's builtin CSS Languages Support extension works is that its server component (which provides completions) uses vscode-css-languageservice, which stores its own generated copy of standard CSS data in src/data/webCustomData.ts. This file is generated based on @vscode/web-custom-data/data/browsers.css-data.json (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data), which in turn is generated from web-data/css/css-schema.json. The values member in webCustomData.ts is used to provide completions. webCustomData.ts doesn't have values for white-space because the source it usually gets it from is not defined in browsers.css-data.json, because the source that usually gets that from is not defined in web-data/css/css-schema.json. This has been brought up in the past: Missing suggestions for "white-space" in CSS #55, and the way it was solved before was to parse the syntax member. But that was a pretty naive implementation and it no longer works because the definition of the syntax has been updated to something more complicated than the original regex will handle.
I've raised a new issue ticket: Regression of white-space values: getValuesFromSyntax no longer handles white-space's syntax #94.

It means that there is no solution for this problem at the moment, right?

@AliDakhili it means there are at least two solutions: you fix it, or you wait for someone else to fix it.

Well, since I just started learning programming, I don't know how to do it myself, is it possible for you to explain to me how to do it?
